Why is IMU directly integrated into ros2_control, but GPS is not?
I'm working on a robot project using ROS 2, and I've noticed that ros2_control has a direct implementation for IMUs, but there's no equivalent for GPS sensors. Since both IMU and GPS are sensors, I’m curious why IMU data is directly integrated into ros2_control for real-time control, while GPS data is not.
Could I create a hardware interface for GPS and use it with ros2_control? Are there any pros or cons to doing this?

No one has added it yet because it seems that GPS is not a rather common sensor within a real-time control loop.
You can add it to your hardware component, if you already use ros2_control this makes totally sense. But this depends on your system (who is using this information?) and how you communicate with your hardware (is it the only sensor on a dedicated bus?).

Thank you for the answer!
I asked about the GPS because I really like the abstraction that ros2_control provides for hardware. I’m considering using ros2_control for all my hardware components for consistency, but I'm not sure yet.
I'm going to integrate GPS and IMU for better localization. Yes, the GPS will be the only sensor on a dedicated bus.

Then you can create several hardware components for every bus and write a custom broadcaster to publish the GPS data.
